# How to mark file when right click on file from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

i have listbox with files in, when i right click on files within the listbox i want the file will marked, how can i do it ?

```
<Window x:Class="myTool.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="myTool" AllowsTransparency="False" Icon="/myTool;component/Images/Organize.ico" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="594" Width="512" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" >

        <ListBox Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,35,0,0" Name="listBoxFiles" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="323" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionMode="Multiple" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="listBoxFiles_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" >
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">

                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_DoubleClick" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" PreviewMouseDown="MenuItem_PreviewMouseDown" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of marking a file?

Comment: when you click on item in the listbox it become blue, that's what i mean marked

Answer (score 1):

The `ListBoxItem` behavior can be extended by implementation of custom attached behavior: add the right button selection aspect. More information about attached behaviors: [Introduction to Attached Behaviors in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF).

```
public static class ListBoxItemBehavior
{
    #region IsEnabled

    public static bool GetIsEnabled(ListBoxItem listBoxItem)
    {
        return (bool)listBoxItem.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsEnabled(ListBoxItem listBoxItem, bool value)
    {
        listBoxItem.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsEnabled",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ListBoxItemBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsEnabledChanged));

    static void OnIsEnabledChanged(
      DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = depObj as ListBoxItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            item.MouseRightButtonDown += ItemOnMouseRightButtonDown;
        else
            item.MouseRightButtonDown -= ItemOnMouseRightButtonDown;
    }

    private static void ItemOnMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = mouseButtonEventArgs.OriginalSource as ListBoxItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.IsSelected = !item.IsSelected;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage (XAML): the attached behavior should be applied for the `ListBoxItem`s of `ListBox`.

Please replace **BEHAVIOR_NAMESPACE** with the full name of namespace where the `ListBoxItemBehavior` class is defined.

```
<Window ...
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:BEHAVIOR_NAMESPACE">
    <ListBox ...
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
      <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
          <Setter Property="Behaviors:ListBoxItemBehavior.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </Style>
      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>

</Window>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: its not recognize the line <Setter Property="Behaviors:ListBoxItemBehavior.IsEnabled" Value="True" /> what should i write ? (my list box properties is in the first comment)

Comment: 'Behaviors:ListBoxItemBehavior' was not found.

Comment: What is the full name of the namespace where `ListBoxItemBehavior` class is defined?

Comment: i did not understand what you asked

Comment: after added this 2 lines i received many errors like The name 'all my controls' does not exist in the current context, please see my updates without this 2 lines (listbox and windows)